# VBA Countif using Arrays as arguments

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I was wondering if there is a possibility to use countif on arrays.

Currently there are two arrays. One is the Array with the Range (RangeArray) and the other the Criteria array (CritArray) which comes from another workbookbut is saved in an array. I'm trying to use the countif method in VBA using arrays if and store the countif values in a cell. So I don't need to loop between workbooks all the time.

```
Dim RangeArray, CritArray as Variant

RangeArray = Array(1,2,3,4,2,4,2,5,7,1,7,1,2)
CritArray = Array(1,2)

For i = 1 To LastRow
    Cells(i, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RangeArray, CriteriaArray)
Next i
```

When I try to do something amongst these lines it keeps giving the error "object required".

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Comment: `Arg1` of `CountIf` must be a `Range`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif).

Comment: What should the result be given the two arrays in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim RangeArray, CritArray As Variant
Dim Counts As New Collection

RangeArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7, 1, 7, 1, 2, 11)
CritArray = Array(1, 2)

For i = 0 To UBound(CritArray)
Count = 0
    For j = 0 To UBound(RangeArray)
    If CritArray(i) = RangeArray(j) Then
    Count = Count + 1
    End If
    Next
Counts.Add Count
Next

For k = 1 To Counts.Count
Cells(k, 1) = Counts(k)
Next
End Sub
```