# Subtracting a comma separated string from another one in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I subtract a comma seperated string from another one in Excel?

- If A1: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`
- And A2: `2,6,9`
- My desired result should be in cell A3, after subtraction (A1-A2): `1,3,4,5,7,8`

It was very easy when `A2=2,3,4` (serially) via `SUBSTITUTE` function, however I can't find a solution to the above.

Comment: Hi Milan, please consider editing your question to make it nicer. Do not use all caps, and elaborate more on your problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would be easy with VBA / UDF .. Use this for a starting point... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565666/vba-countif-using-arrays-as-arguments/60566417#60566417

Comment: Please don't change the question if you have another question. Post another quesiton instead. Refer to this question if needed.

Comment: For the sake of future Googlers: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/extracting-differences-between-two-comma-separated-strings.1089224/post-5234846 provides a concise solution if what you need is **set difference**, even though the function is confusingly named `GetUnique`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have both tagged formula and VBA. So let me give you two options too:

---

**1)** Formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1&","&A2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(following::*=. or preceding::*=.)]"))
```

***Note1:*** This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

***Note2:*** This requires access to the `TEXTJOIN` function, available in office 365 and Excel 2019.

***Note3:*** More usefull `FILTERXML` "tricks" can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)

---

**2)** UDF

I'd recommend using `Split` and `Join` functions to do this:

```
Function TxtFilter(val1 As String, val2 As String, sep As String) As String

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

arr1 = Split(val1, sep)
arr2 = Split(val2, sep)

'Iterate first array to load dictionary
For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    dict(arr1(x)) = 1
Next x

'Iterate second array to remove from dictionary
For x = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
    If dict.Exists(arr2(x)) Then dict.Remove arr2(x)
Next x

'Join remainder back together
TxtFilter = Join(dict.keys, sep)

End Function
```

Call in any cell through `=TxtFilter(A1,A2,",")`

Comment: Great... Like the UDF

Comment: Yes Great It made my day , I m very very grateful to you